# Vuejs - change sub element's img source when parent has "active" class

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
         <router-link to="/">
            <div class="menu-item">
                <div class="menu-item-image"><img
                        src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg"
                        alt=""></div>
                <a class="menu-item-text-selected">Dashboard</a>
            </div>
        </router-link>
```

Have code like above.

When a link clicked **router-link** adds `router-link-exact-active` class to parent but i need to change the src of the sub image. Any suggestion? I can bind a method to click and perform required action but that does not seem right. Any elegant solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could use CSS, instead of using an image go for a background image. Define a background image for the normal state `.menu-item-image {  background: url(imgSrc) }` then for the active state `.router-link-exact-active .menu-item-image {  background: url(activeImgSrc) }`

Comment: @Ricky That would require multiple classes then.